# nginx with multiple locations not working - error 404

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am setting up nginx to serve two websites using proxy as follows,

```
server {
listen                 80;

proxy_set_header HOST $proxy_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://<website-1>;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
}

location /bmo {
    proxy_pass http://<website-2>;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
}

}
```

Proxy to website-1 is working, but website-2 is giving error 404. Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: Does the proxy work? So can you see an access on `website-2` (for example in logfiles)?

Comment: Access log gets this message: 
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "http://awspad12345.com/bmo" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36" "-" 

awspad12345.com is the server where nginx is configured.

Answer (score 0):

You get 404 code, because the second site is missing path `/bmo`, correct?

In your example url proxing to `http://<website-2>/bmo`.

Nginx config on the proxy is valid and correctly, check you config on the `website-2`